# Android: find fastest route between 2 or more points depeding on streets in GoogleMaps

Tags: android, google-maps, shortest-path, google-elevation-api

Am adding markers in my app on `GoogleMaps`,my markers allways are on streets.For example I have moore than 2 markers on map, I need to draw optimal route between them depending on streets.Is there any service to help me, or I need to create my own algorithm? Until now I worked a little with `Google Elevation API` and `Google Direction API`, but now I need `Google Roads API`, to find optimal roads between points? It must be something simmilar to my needs.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using following library: https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary

```
GoogleDirection.withServerKey("YOUR_SERVER_API_KEY")
        .from(new LatLng(37.7681994, -122.444538))
            .to(new LatLng(37.7749003,-122.4034934))
            .avoid(AvoidType.FERRIES)
            .avoid(AvoidType.HIGHWAYS)
            .execute(new DirectionCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onDirectionSuccess(Direction direction, String rawBody) {
        if(direction.isOK()) {
            // Do something
        } else {
            // Do something
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDirectionFailure(Throwable t) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

Gradle

```
compile 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.0.5'
```